# Azure how to change premium blob storage to standard blob storage account?

Tags: azure, blob, storage

Azure how to change premium blob storage to standard blob storage account?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to change premium blob storage account to standard blob storage account, you can copy the data from premium blob storage account to standard blob, then delete the premium blob storage account.
About copy data, you can use [Azcopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-use-azcopy) or [Azure storage explorer](http://storageexplorer.com/).

Comment: Is the reverse possible?